# Is is possible to make helpers private in WebMatrix?

Tags: helper, access-modifiers, webmatrix

I've created my own data grid helper in WebMatrix.  The paging and sorting links are helpers too, but I don't really want to expose those helpers publicly to the rest of the app.

For example:

```
@helper Pager(IEnumerable<dynamic> gridData,
    int totalRows, int currentPage, int rowsPerPage)
{
    // Helper code is here.
}
```

Is there any way to make a helper private?  Would that be a bad practice, anyway?  I know there are private functions, but helpers are handy from a syntactic standpoint.

Comment: I think of helpers as methods added to avoid the duplication of code. Making these private would defeat that purpose, as you'd have to copy and paste the helper into each place you'd want to reuse it. Is there any reason you want to prevent the code from being reused?

Comment: druttka - I am using the page and link helpers for code reuse - just within the grid helper itself.  I'm used to OOP and encapsulation where private methods are common.  I could very easily just create some actual private methods, but I like the helper syntax in Razor.  No big deal (this is a simple project, hence the use of WebMatrix).  Just curious if this was possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `@helper` syntax means that your helper method will automatically get compiled to a `public` `static` method. So the answer to your question is no.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to create a library and reference it in your web.config or .cshtml file.
helpers bascially output the html you need/want, essentially htmlhelpers return an html string. You would have to move all your code out into the library and its separate from your main app.